# pass list of complex objects to controller

Tags: java, list, jsp, controller

I have a list of items (List) that I pass to a JSP page via a get request.

```
@RequestMapping(value="value", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getItems(ModelMap model) {
    List<Item> items = itemDataService.getItems();
    model.addAttribute("items", items);
}
```

The JSP looks like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div id=itemsList>
        <div class="box">
            <table class="display" width="100%">
                <theader>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Item Description</th>
                    <th>Accept Setting</th>
                </theader>
                <tbody class="list">
                    <c:forEach var="item" items="${items}" varStatus="loopStatus">
                        <tr>
                            <td> ${item.name}</td>                              
                            <td>${item.description}</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Items">
</form>
```

What I would like to do now is, when I hit the submit button of my form I would like to pass a list of items back to the controller. My problem here is that I am not sure of how to name the fields in the  section so that every table row is seen as an item and how to make sure that those items will be send to the controller as a list.

So far my POST method in the controller looks as following:

```
@RequestMapping(value="value", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void onSubmit(ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println("##################### FORM SUBMIT");
}
```

Triggering the POST action when submitting the form works so far, but how do I pass the data?
The item class itself has getters and setters for name and description and the checkbox value...

Comment: Do you want to pass the `checked` value from the check box or the entire items ?

Comment: the checked value only refers to the state of the checkbox. But the value needs to be stored as part of the item attributes

Comment: You need to send the checked value to the controller . am i correct with my understanding ?

Comment: I want to send the entire item back to the controller - so name, description and the checkbox value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the spring `form` tag.

Hope they have the respective setter and getter methods,

```
<form:form method="post" action="update" modelAttribute="Objectname">
    <div id=itemsList>
        <div class="box">
            <table class="display" width="100%">
                <theader>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Item Description</th>
                    <th>Accept Setting</th>
                </theader>
                <tbody class="list">
                    <c:forEach var="item" items="${items}" varStatus="loopStatus">
                        <tr>
                            <td> ${item.name}</td>                              
                            <td>${item.description}</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Items">
</form:form>
```

And in the controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value="value", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void onSubmit(@ModelAttribute ModelClass Objectname) {
    Objectname.getterMethod();
    System.out.println("##################### FORM SUBMIT");
 }
```

hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

You have a list in Java that you are sending that to JSP and then sending back the same list to Java again right? If my understanding is correct, I would suggest you to store the list in session scope before you pass to JSP(i.e. in the getItems method), when you submit the form in JSP, get the list from the session attribute in the onSubmit method.